# JBPM process designer - WebServices

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I am trying to add a WebService Service Task to a process in JBPM. I would like to add and configure the task directly from the process design tool.

JBPM has 3 possible tools that you can use to create a process, eclipse plugins: RulesFlow editor and BPMN2 Modeler, as well as a Onyx Designer incorporated into Drools. So far I have not managed to do this in any of them.

I was able to add the WS to the process by manually editing the process XML file (as shown here: http://mswiderski.blogspot.com/2012/07/service-task-with-web-service.html) but we need to be able to do it in a graphical tool (business reasons, don't ask). BPMN2 Modeler comes closest to the generated XML that would in theory work, but when I try to run it, it comes out with a bunch of errors.

I know that the link I provided states that the tools don't yet provide the WS functionality but maybe someone has some ideas as to this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can directly create a service task from the design tools. I've followed this [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.domain-specific-processes.html) :

And after you've created your work item definition, you should be able to see that you can add that service task in your process design. Just remember that you have to register that to your session before you start the process. Hope this helps